# Dynamically building an if statement based on the number of array keys present

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have a PHP function in which I pass in a string or array of column names. Unfortunately, this can become a bit problematic and cumbersome depending on the number of column names that I get.

As such, is there a way that I can rewrite my if statement so that I dynamically can build the conditional based on the number of elements I have in my array?

I would usually run a check to see if a value was in the array, however as these are key values of another array, it makes things more complicated. Below is my current code.

```
private function pushToArray($list, $columnName, $date) {
    $array = [];
    foreach($list as $item) {
        if (is_array($columnName)){
            if ($date == $item[$columnName[0]] || $date == $item[$columnName[1]]) {
                array_push($array, $item);
            }
        } else {
            if ($date == $item[$columnName]) {
                array_push($array, $item);
            }
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

As can be seen here, as my array increase in elements, I would have to add additional if conditions to handle the larger array set. Something I would like to avoid.

EDIT:
Right now, I am using laravel as the framework for my application. I am trying to generate an array that will populate a view of an upcoming event system.
Here is a sample of the current calls:

```
$separatedArray = $this->pushToArray($this->separatedList(), 'destroyed_date', $currentDate);
$travelsArray = $this->pushToArray($this->travelsList(), ['leave_date','return_date'], $currentDate);
$trainingUsersArray = $this->pushToArray($this->trainingUsersList(), 'due_date', $currentDate);
```

Here is a sample of some of the code before I moved it to its own function.

```
        $separatedArray = $travelsArray = $trainingUsersArray = [];
        $currentDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');

        foreach($separatedList as $user) {
            if ($currentDate == $user->destroyed_date) {
                array_push($separatedArray, $user);
            }
        }

        foreach($travels as $travel) {
            if ($currentDate == $travel->leave_date || $currentDate == $travel->return_date) {
                array_push($travelsArray, $travel);
            }
        }
        foreach($trainingUsers as $trainingUser) {
            if ($currentDate == $trainingUser->due_date) {
                array_push($trainingUsersArray, $trainingUser);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like what you really have is a database design issue.  Can you elaborate on what your real goal is, and provide some example data?  Please provide example input and desired output.

Comment: I have updated my original query, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace code of first if block with foreach loop.

```
if (is_array($columnName)) {
    foreach ($columnName as $column) {
        if ($date == $item[$column]) {
            array_push($array, $item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I couldn't think of this. Thank you. I will have to add a check to make sure we are not adding the same item multiple times, but this is pretty much what I was seeking.